# dynamic rowspan problem in table in laravel (product variations)

Tags: php, laravel, foreach, html-table

Consider the original output for example:

[image]

And then I want rowspan like this

[image]

Array code:

[image]

Here is my laravel code:

```php
foreach ($color as $key => $val) {
    foreach ($size as $key1 => $val1) {
        $data .=
            '<tr>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
        <input class="" type="checkbox" id="blankCheckbox" value="option1" aria-label="...">
         </td>
            <td class="py-1">' . $key1 . '</td> 
            <td>' . strtoupper($val) . '</td>
            <td>' . strtoupper($val1) . '</td>
            <td>' . ($same_price_flag === true ? '' : '<input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">') . '</td>
            <td>' . ($same_price_flag === true ? '' : '<input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">') . '</td>
            <td>' . ($same_price_flag === true ? '' : '<input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">') . '</td>
            <td>' . ($same_price_flag === true ? '' : '<input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off">') . '</td>
            <td><input type="text" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
            <td><input type="number" class="form-control" autocomplete="off"></td>
        </tr>
            ';
    }
}

}
```